# Calling protected API from VueJS/Express via Access Token?

Tags: jwt, vue.js

I'm trying to understand how Auth flows work within VueJS/Express Server to a protected API.

I have a situation where I need to call an API that is protected by JWT. To get this JWT, a client ID and secret is sent to an auth server which returns a token which is then passed in the header when calling the protected API, obviously these credentials need to be kept secure.

The app that is calling the API is an SPA built using VueJS and is running an express server to power it, the question I have is how do I call the auth server securely to get a JWT when I can't store a client ID or secret in the SPA app?

This doesn't require the user to authenticate as this data isn't protected for the users sake, it is more the data is specific for a products dataset that is only accessible to anyone with an app ID and secret, so there wouldn't be an "authorisation prompt" so to speak.

So can I use express in the backend to securely call the API? but if I do that, surely anyone can call my express instance when its running in Azure if they know the URL?

I've looked into a few authentication methods and ways of doing this but they all suggest that the user is prompted for authorisation rather than an app or SPA calling a protected endpoint with appID/secret combination.

I think my main concerns here are; if I securely call the API from my express server, then use my SPA to call into the express server, what is stopping a rogue actor from doing the same and freely calling an endpoint that then calls a protected API?

Comment: Have you tried enabling CORS? The express server (or any other infrastructure component between the spa and the express server) checks and validates the origin of the request. It's a (more or less) white list of IPs, domains, subdomains, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I think my main concerns here are; if I securely call the API from my express server, then use my SPA to call into the express server, what is stopping a rogue actor from doing the same and freely calling an endpoint that then calls a protected api?

What is stopping a rogue actor is the authentication flow you have between your SPA and express server to make sure only legitimate users of your SPA can make a successful call to that endpoint of the express server.